# Using update-java-alternatives with openjdk 8 updates java but not javac

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 and have several JDKs installed. When I use `update-java-alternatives` to select openjdk8, this updates `java` but not `javac`, which defaults to "auto" (which in my case selects javac from openjdk9).

```
grodriguez@ubuntu:~$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64 1061 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 1069 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64 1079 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.9.0-openjdk-amd64
grodriguez@ubuntu:~$ sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
[sudo] password for grodriguez: 
update-alternatives: error: no hay alternativas para mozilla-javaplugin.so
update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
grodriguez@ubuntu:~$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-8u141-b15-3~14.04-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
grodriguez@ubuntu:~$ javac -version
javac 9.0.4
```

This problem does not exist when selecting a different version via update-java-alternatives. For example, selecting `java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64` works fine (both `java` and `javac` are properly updated).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in 'update-java-alternatives`.

- Debian bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825987
- Ubuntu bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/java-common/+bug/1603692

These reports also contain patches to fix the described behaviour.